# Add "Size Guide" button or Icon to product pages

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce

I sell shoes and clothes on [My Website](http://www.pareshstore.com) and I need to add an option for sizing guide. Probably you have seen it on most websites. Below the "add to cart" there is a small icon for "size guide". I need to make a button or icon to be able to show size charts. For example you can see this website :

http://www.zalando.co.uk/nike-sportswear-md-runner-txt-trainers-grey-ni112a02i-c11.html

I'd be much appreciated if you could help me step by step because I am beginner.

thank you

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/-woocommerce-product-chart-sizes-table/7248628

Comment: @starvator , thanks, what do you mean by broad? I dont know if I conveyed it or not, but I guess it should be very simple (not for me though). I just need a text with link under size attribute. 
http://www.pareshstore.com/product/kobe-8-system-%D8%AE%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AF-%DA%A9%D9%81%D8%B4-%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%B2%D8%B4%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84

Comment: @Len_D , I have alrady added a custom tab, so I dont need that plugin. I'd rather just use a small code than a new plugin. Thank you though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add whatever you'd like to a hook right after the add to cart form.

```
function so_26388014_after_add_to_cart(){
    echo '<a id="size_guide" href="#link-to-size-guide" title="Size Guide">Size Guide</a>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'so_26388014_after_add_to_cart' );
```

At first I thought you might need some conditional logic, but the `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form` hook really should only be showing on single product pages, so you probably don't need to use `is_product()` or similar.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick, 
can you help with styling it? I need to add some pedding and change the color, and also put a link to it. I want to link it to the third tab on product page (size chart tab) . Should I use "so_26388014_after_add_to_cart" to call it for styling?

http://tinyurl.com/qeoe2rf

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: What if its under a specific category? i tried if is_product_category()...condtional statements, it won't work

Comment: [`is_product_category()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-5) Returns true when viewing a product category archive. If you want to check if a product has a particular term you probably need [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/)